# how to convert ipv4 to ipv6 address using TCL

Tags: tcl

Given any ipv4 Ip address (for example: 10.24.13.91), should convert it into ipv6 address(expected output: ::FFFF:0A18:0D5B )
How to write TCL Script that will convert any ipv4 address to ipv6 address as above.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ip` package in Tcllib](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/dns/tcllib_ip.md) is helpful here, but doesn't do the whole job. (You're after making an IPv4-mapped IPv6 address, as defined in [RFC 3513](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3513.txt).)

```
package require ip

proc IPv4toIPv6 {addr} {
    if {![ip::is ipv4 $addr]} {
        error "need an IPv4 address"
    }
    set raw [ip::toInteger $addr]
    return [ip::normalize [format "::FFFF:%04x:%04x" [expr {$raw >> 16}] [expr {$raw & 0xFFFF}]]]
}

set v6 [IPv4toIPv6 10.24.13.91]
puts "Full address: $v6"
# Full address: 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:ffff:0a18:0d5b
puts "Abbreviated: [ip::contract $v6]"
# Abbreviated: ::ffff:a18:d5b
```

Looks right to me.

Comment: Thank you so much @Donal for your kind reply. Let me try out executing it.

Comment: The logic will not work for the Ips like 255.255.0.0

Answer (score 0):

```
   proc IPv4toIPv6 { addr } {
        if {![ip::is ipv4 $addr]} {
            error "addr should be an IPv4 address"
        }
        set raw 0
        set octets [lreverse [split $addr .]]
        for { set i 0 } { $i < 4 } { incr i } {
            set raw [expr { 256 ** $i * [lindex $octets $i ] + $raw }]
            }

        set ipv6 [ip::normalize [format "::FFFF:%04x:%04x" [expr {$raw >> 16}] [expr {$raw & 0xFFFF}]]]
        return [ip::contract $ipv6]
    }
```

Just a workaround. The above logic will work for any Ipv4 ips as expected. !!!!